# SELECT DISTINCT returns duplicates - no table JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

**Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2550.0 (X64)**

My client sent me an Excel spreadsheet which I've imported into SQL Server using the Data Import function.

During the data cleansing operation I've been identifying duplicate or near-duplicate rows and this process is 99% complete.

However, I've come completely unstuck because executing this SQL from the Query window

```
SELECT DISTINCT MyTextColumn FROM MyTable WHERE MyCriterion = 'TEST'
```

returns *two apparently identical records*.

Initially I tried

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEN(MyTextColumn) FROM MyTable WHERE MyCriterion = 'TEST'
```

but this returned a single value - in other words, the two values were the same length.

I've put the two values of MyTextColumn into Notepad++ and done a COMPARE and allegedly the "files are identical".  I've converted the two values to HEX and compared them - again, identical.

NOTE - The values obtained from the Spreadsheet were VarChar(255) and the destination column is varchar(max).  Not nvarchar, but varchar.  I've also looked for a solution elsewhere on stackoverflow but almost all other such questions involve a JOIN.

The only thing I can think of is that in "getting" the two values into Notepad++ (by simply highlighting them in the Query results window and copying and pasting) is somehow "missing" some vital component of the column.

Does anyone have any idea why this might not be working?  I fully appreciate that other values in other columns in MyTable will differ, but my understanding is that the DISTINCT keyword operates ONLY on columns in the SELECT statement.

Many thanks

Edward

Comment: LEN does TRIM before it calculates the length of a string. From the [docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx) *Returns the number of characters of the specified string expression, excluding trailing blanks.*

Comment: Yes, what happens when you try `SELECT DISTINCT LTRIM(RTRIM(MyTextColumn)) ...` ?

Comment: Beat me to it, @YuriyGalanter... Must be surrounding whitespace.

Comment: Adding SELECT DISTINCT LTRIM(RTRIM(MyTextColumn)) has no effect.  Still returns two rows.

Comment: To help you debug the problem, try using `SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(MyTextColumn, ###) FROM MyTable WHERE MyCriterion = 'TEST'` Start `###` at roughly half the length of your text. If you get two entries, the first diff is to the left of `###`; divide it by two. Otherwise, it's to the right; adjust to three quarters of the length. Continue with this "binary search" until you hit the point where the texts differ from each other.

Comment: Ah, very interesting.  `SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(MyTextColumn, 98)` returns one row, whereas `SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(MyTextColumn, 99)` returns two.

What next?

Comment: Well, you can now do a `SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(MyTextColumn,99,1)` and inspect the results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Lamak.

`SELECT DISTINCT ASCII(SUBSTRING(MyTextColumn, 99, 1))`

returns two rows - one is 10, the other is 32. Many thanks to all participants